# The back of my laptop is kinda popping off

Tags: laptop-repair

The back isn't cracked or anything just popping off. It only starts to pop off when  I start to close it or adjust it any way that's towards the keyboard/me. I can pop it back in but it doesn't stick. Any advice?

Comment: Is the battery expanding? What model is the laptop? Can you share a picture?

Comment: Some laptops are glued; some rely on snapping into place; some are attached by screws you can see when you remove the bezel inside. We won't know what you have until you tell us. Please find the serial number sticker or plate on the bottom, and get the true model number from there; marketing model numbers on the lid or bezels are often worthless. Click [edit] and add it to your original question. Please don't click [Add Comment] to reply; comments can get pushed down the screen and hidden under a link. We want everyone to see details they need to help you which means put it in the Question.